Terminal is showing Module '"next-auth"' has no exported member 'AuthOptions'
Im working on a Nextjs Project 15.0.3.
Using next-auth.js for Authentication.While setting up my app/api/auth/[...nextauth].ts page ,
I am getting the following ERROR:
Module '"next-auth"' has no exported member 'AuthOptions'. Did you mean to use 'import AuthOptions from "next-auth"' instead?
Binding element 'user' implicitly has an 'any' type.
Binding element 'account' implicitly has an 'any' type.
Binding element 'profile' implicitly has an 'any' type.

This seems to be a issue of Typescript incompactibility.
Attaching my [...nextauth.ts] code:
import NextAuth from "next-auth";
import GoogleProvider from "next-auth/providers/google";


export const authOptions = {
    providers : 
    [
    GoogleProvider({clientId : process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID , clientSecret : process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET}),
    ],
    callbacks :{
        async signIn({ user, account, profile }
        {    return true;   },
        async redirect({ url, baseUrl }
        {   return "/details"   }
    },
};

const handler  = NextAuth(authOptions);

export {handler as GET  , handler as POST};


Tried importing Type {AuthOptions}from nextauth.
But error still persists.
Also defined Types of SignIn and redirect as  Promise<Boolean> and .Promise` respectively

next auth is now authjs (nextjs auth v5 beta). are you using v4?

You are missing two closing ")" and satisfies NextAuthOptions. Please try this:
import NextAuth, {NextAuthOptions} from "next-auth";
import GoogleProvider from "next-auth/providers/google";

const authOptions = {
    providers:
        [
            GoogleProvider({
                clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID || "", // added fallback
                clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET || "" // added fallback
            }),
        ],
    callbacks: {
        async signIn({user, account, profile}) { // added closing ")"
            return true;
        },
        async redirect({url, baseUrl}) { // added closing ")"
            return "/details"
        }
    },
} satisfies NextAuthOptions; // added

const handler = NextAuth(authOptions);

export {handler as GET, handler as POST};

